# Rails, uploading a file using only file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I need to upload a file in rails without any gems, so I decided just to use

```
<%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
```

without any form and etc. Just file_field and in controller I tried to catch it with

```
name =  params[:upload][:datafile].original_filename
```

it shows me an error:

```
undefined method `original_filename' for "me.jpg":String
```

my params:

```
"upload"=>{"datafile"=>"me.jpg"}
```

It seems that I cannot use only file_field alone without any form, can I? Or I should alway include it into a form? If yes, is it possible to do it without using a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please verify you have added multipart: true option in your form_tag or not.

Syntax:-

```
<%= form_tag '/upload', multipart: true do %>
 <label for="file">File to Upload</label> <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
 <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using form you should use FormTagHelper  `file_field_tag`

this might help you [FormTagHelper/file_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag)